# How to remove black background from geoserver imagepyramid?

Tags: geoserver, image-pyramids

I have a large ImagePyramid published in Geoserver (v 2.4). Each granule in the pyramid has nodata set to 0. I'm confused as to which layer parameter in GeoServer should I change to get a transparent background. I tried changing `BackgroundValues`; `InputTransparentColor` and `OutputTransparentColor` but nothing seemed to work.

How can I make the background transparent?

[image: Black color in the background that I'd like to remove]

Comment: Tried several alternatives, changing output transparent color etc. None worked. Beginning to believe it's not possible to do this with image pyramids.

Comment: One more reason to believe transparent border does not work in ImagePyramid. If I publish just one of the ImagePyramid tiles and set InputTransparentColor to 000000 I don't get the border. But that is for one single tile, not for the entire pyramid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out it's a styling problem. I'm using a custom RasterSymboliser style to show bands 3,2,1 and not (1,2,3). By doing that, the alpha channel is not respected and I get no transparency. This post talks a bit about this issue: [Setting transparency in an SLD file for a 4 channel GEOTIFF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41472/setting-transparency-in-an-sld-file-for-a-4-channel-geotiff)

I tried setting nodata value to each pyramid granule but that did not work. So I'll probably end up composing my pyramid using the final band combination (3,2,1) and use the default raster style.