# Can't set transparent raster alpha channel in GeoExplorer!

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to get transparent parts of an 3-channel raster with NoData pixel values in GeoServer.

As suggested in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41472/setting-transparency-in-an-sld-file-for-a-4-channel-geotiff), I created alpha channel with pixels that have No Data Value (0) as a mask using GDAL
`gdalwarp -srcnodata 0 -dstalpha input.tif output.tif`
As a result I got 4-channel (RGB+alpha) where the pixels that previously were 0 now have 0 values in all four channels and those, that were > 0, in alpha channel have value 255. Also No Data Value is set to 0.

When I upload raster to GeoServer (v2.5.2) using QGIS plugin OpenGeo Explorer, instead of transparent pixels I get black pixels. What could be the problem? I have also tried without setting No Data Value without results.

---------------EDIT----------------
Geoserver version: 2.5.2
Raster style:

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>    <sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
>      <sld:NamedLayer>
> <sld:Name>RGB raster</sld:Name>
> <sld:UserStyle>
>   <sld:Name>RGB raster</sld:Name>
>   <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
>     <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
>     <sld:Rule>
>       <sld:Name>Single symbol</sld:Name>
>       <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
>         <sld:ChannelSelection>
>           <sld:RedChannel>
>             <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
>           </sld:RedChannel>
>           <sld:GreenChannel>
>             <sld:SourceChannelName>2</sld:SourceChannelName>
>           </sld:GreenChannel>
>           <sld:BlueChannel>
>             <sld:SourceChannelName>3</sld:SourceChannelName>
>           </sld:BlueChannel>
>         </sld:ChannelSelection>
>       </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
>     </sld:Rule>
>   </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
> </sld:UserStyle>
> ```

Here is the request:
request=GetMap&layers=jaun:ORO2&styles=&bbox=515813.19564,305943.471,516026.19564,306105.471&width=512&height=389&srs=EPSG:3059&format=application/openlayers&transparent=true

Comment: Can you share the following information:

 1. version of geoserver
 2. style you are using to show the data
 3. GetMap format you are asking from GeoExplorer

Simone.

Comment: Updated qoestion text with requested information!

Comment: Basically all i need is for GeoExplorer to show trasparency where image alpha band pixel value is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao,
the style you are using is stripping out the alpha band.
Use the standard/default raster.sld style.

Simone.