# MBTiles with GeoServer: how to hide white nodata tiles?

Tags: raster, geoserver, mbtiles

I published MBTiles with GeoServer. When I open it in QGIS I get:

[image]

You see that the area around the tiles is white.
Before I generated the MBTiles I tried [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41472/setting-transparency-in-an-sld-file-for-a-4-channel-geotiff) but I get the same result.

How can I hide these white tiles? And how to find the reason why they appear on the map? Because when I open the MBTiles directly in QGIS I do not see any white tiles.

Answer (score 1):

What image format are you viewing the map as?

JPG doesn't support transparency, so it'll display empty areas as white.

If you use PNG, it does support transparency, so you should see empty areas.

Here's where you choose what image format to use in QGIS:

[image: Add layer from WMS - pick image format]

Answer (score 0):

The MB tiles itself are made using osm as base map.so no matter where you load it the base map will come. you have to recreate the mb tile. you can use free softwares such as tilemill to do so . also the below link will help you . I would suggest not to use geoserver to publish mbtiles. there are many other softwares that can do same very easily.

https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/wiki/Implementations