# GeoServer WMS removes color from 4 band image

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have loaded a set of 4 band (R,G,B,NIR) GeoTIFF files in GeoServer and I am accessing the data via WMS. My problem is that whenever the NIR band contains a value of 0, that in the WMS output image the R, G and B bands are also cleared of their values and set to white. This is not what I want.

The input GeoTIFF images have no nodata value set. So why is GeoServer use the NIR 0 value as nodata? Below are the settings:

[image: GeoServer layer settings]

I tried to use the input and output transparent color, but once I set them the WMS only returns 3 bands in the image and the 4th NIR band is no longer there, so that doesn't help either.

And how can I configure GeoServer to just return the data in the input image without changing it?

Comment: You might need to use WCS

Comment: I believe that the fourth band is interpreted to be an alpha band. Have a try by select just the three first bands with SLD like in this question  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41472/setting-transparency-in-an-sld-file-for-a-4-channel-geotiff.  If you need all 4 bands, use WCS. WMS is for visualizing and then only either one or three bands make sense.

Comment: @user30184, thanks for the suggestion. I really need all four bands, so only selecting the first three won't help in my case. I tried the SLD approach and in that case the colours are correct indeed. But I need the 4th band in my processing as well.

I guess I might have to switch to WCS in this case. Until now WMS worked fine with the 4 bands, but that was probably because the images I used before the 4th band was never exactly zero. If there is no way to prevent the WMS from altering the RGB values when the 4th band is zero, I guess using WCS is the only option.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the values of the fourth band from 0 to 1 and fool the rendering?

Comment: OK, I'll modify my workflow to use WCS instead, that's easier than having to modify all data. Thanks for the help.