# No data value in geotiff rendered as white backgroud in geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have a geotiff file which contains three bands and the value is 'no-data' at the edge of the image:

[image]

However after published in geoserver, I got this:

[image]

Note the white background in the image, while I want it is transparent.

Is this possible?

---

update:

I use the following command `gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -of GTiff D:/01.tif D:/02.tif` in qgis to translate the geotiff file.

When publish in geoserver I set the `InputTransparentColor` to 0:

[image]

And the default raster style in geoserver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor>
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>default_raster</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Default Raster</Title>
      <Abstract></Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Opaque Raster</Title>
          <Abstract>A raster with 100% opacity</Abstract>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
            <ChannelSelection> 
              <RedChannel> 
                <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName> 
              </RedChannel> 
              <GreenChannel> 
                <SourceChannelName>2</SourceChannelName> 
              </GreenChannel> 
              <BlueChannel> 
                <SourceChannelName>3</SourceChannelName> 
              </BlueChannel> 
            </ChannelSelection>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10674/transparent-raster-in-geoserver might help.

Comment: I have tried that, and use gdal_translate to convert the tiff, does not work.

Comment: I don't think you read the answers in the link I provided. You don't have an colormap with opacity 0 for your nodata value. I also don't think you specified the nodata value (0) when you wrote `FFFFFF`.

Comment: I follow this link 'http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10674/transparent-raster-in-geoserver#comment86908_10676'

Comment: Maybe you mean the `FFFFFF` it is auto changed by geoserver once I enter `0` for the field.

Comment: Or to really put a transparency value into your SLD, as shown in the linked example.